Data inconsistencies between Pyspark dataframe and toPandas()
After making some transformation to a dataframe using pyspark (that include deleting the values of some rows) and then converting it to Pandas using .toPandas(), I realize that the resulting pandas dataframe is not the same as the Spark dataframe, but instead still contains the deleted rows.
Code example:
df = df.withColumn("ID", monotonically_increasing_id())

anomaly_ids = [15699, 48526, 81592]

# Substitute all values in columns with anomaly IDs, retain ID and TIMESTAMP values
for col_name in [col for col in df.columns if col not in ["ID", "TIMESTAMP"]]:
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, when(df["ID"].isin(anomaly_ids), lit(None)).otherwise(df[col_name]))

Getting the max values of one of the columns:
df.select(F.max(col("TEMPERATURE"))).show()

> +--------------------------+
> |     max(TEMPERATURE)     |
> +--------------------------+
> |                        38|
> +--------------------------+

Now, if we convert the df to pandas and get the max value of the column we get:
dfx = df.select("*").toPandas()
dfx["TEMPERATURE"].max()

> 659.0

It's a relatively small dataframe of 80.000 rows and 40 columns.

can you provide a working minimum reproducible example ?

spark is lazy and it runs the entire lineage every time. hence, your monotonically_increasing_id() will be executed in every action separately which results in different IDs across the iterations/actions.

As @samkart mentioned, you are likely regenerating IDs when calling show() and toPandas(). Try this code to avoid regeneration df = df.withColumn("ID", monotonically_increasing_id()).cache()

Thank you @AlexanderPavlov & @ samkart, caching the generated index column seemed to have solved the issue

keep in mind, you did not cache ID column, you cached entire DataFrame, so on large datasets it may require large storage or could even fail.
